# How bind my subdomain to my tomcat project on ubuntu with Vesta CP

Tags: java, php, tomcat, apache2, vesta

I have remote server with one IP adress, where i having java and php projects. PHP project working with Vesta CP and java projects work with Tomcat 9. I have several domains and subdomains for my java projects, but i do not know how bind my subdomains with my java projects.

For example, i want joining this subdomain **diagram.mathzilla.org** with my project, which is available by adress and port http://78.24.217.121:8085/MZDiagram/.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't bind two different servers (Apache Tomcat and Apache httpd) to same IP & port. But you can use mod_rewrite for Apache httpd for redirect some queries to other port inside server.

For example:

Tomcat is running on port 8085 and httpd is on port 80. In httpd for virtual host diagram.mathzilla.org you can redirect all queries to port 8085 via .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:8085/$1 [P]
```

Comment: Create htaccess with `RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://78.24.217.121:8085/MZDiagram/ [P]` It is work, but i have error in js console and project is not load [http://diagram.mathzilla.org/](http://diagram.mathzilla.org/). Why?

Comment: Add $1 to the end of rediredt URL:  `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://78.24.217.121:8085/MZDiagram/$1 [P]`

Comment: `$1`, not `1$` :)